# Is it illegal to deliberately cause someone stress?

Tags: european-union, tort

It is not legal in most countries to disrupt someone's success, but mental stress does cause disruption. Thus, the question is: Is deliberately causing someone distress illegal? And if so, in which forms?

I am primarily looking for answers to the European Union, but I am interested to see answers to other jurisdictions as well.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You might want to clarify it. For instance, stress is not an infection (see the title). Also mixing the notions of *success* and *mental distress* in your question creates confusion as to what exactly you want to know. Lastly, what do you mean by "[which] forms"? do you mean "forms of *distress*" that are illegal to cause? or do you mean illegal "*methods* of which the purpose is to cause mental distress"?

Comment: I don't know of any country where is it illegal to "disrupt someone's success": perhaps you can explain what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

**At the time of the question this was likely illegal in at least one country within the European Union, in the UK**

where the case may — regardless of Brexit — still be similarly illegal to this day.

In Common Law systems under tort theory (including in the UK), it is not legal to [intentionally inflict severe emotional or less frequently, "mental" distress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentional_infliction_of_emotional_distress) upon another under certain circumstances, and the wrongdoer may be liable for damages towards the sufferer.

Another tort, [negligent infliction of emotional distress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligent_infliction_of_emotional_distress), may also entitle one to damages although this cause of action is not available in all States of the United States.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the degree of stress. A court has to observe the stress objectively as in based on the reasonable person and if it has caused damage psychologically. It does not have the resources to do otherwise and analyse subjectively by looking into their minds.

I do not believe it is ‘illegal’ however, I think it acts more as a civil wrong at this point in time, depending on the country you are in. Illegal would imply that it can be trailed criminally which in some cases might not be possible.

As for Australia, it would come into question under the fair work act when it comes to employment matters and the obligations on the employers to ensure the health and safety of employees.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of any laws explicitly making a criminal offence of causing someone stress.

Undoubtedly stress can be a *consequence* of civil wrong or criminal behaviour such as workplace bullying, sexual harassment, stalking, mugging, burglary, extortion, assault, fraud... the list goes on. But the defendant isn't accused of causing stress, they're accused of the bullying or burglary (or whatever).

Comment: The question did not narrowly relate only to "criminal offence[s]" (sic!) but to its legality which may be negated by civil law measures as well, and which such actions are, at least in Common Law systems when the act is "intentional", and acting deliberately includes intentionality.